# Anyway to find out what program is asking for admin credentials?

Tags: macos, mac

I've got a user's iMac that seems to be asking for admin credentials more often than it should be, all it says is that Mac OS requires admin credentials. Is there a way of finding out what application is asking for it?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the dialog.  That one doesn't sound familiar.

Comment: Also a good idea to include the version of macOS in your original post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ICloud Password prompt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230748/icloud-password-prompt)

Comment: re duplicate the question differs but the answer is I think the same

Comment: @Mark the other question is about iCloud, with iCloud specific answers. What makes you thing they apply here as well, and how do they help identifying the application triggering the prompt?

Comment: The notification is the same app I think howevr I am not certain so perhaps not

Answer (score 1):

I would configure syslog to record those details into a file.

Assuming that you are comfortable with editing text files from the command prompt, use your favorite editor and edit /etc/syslog.conf adding this line:

```
auth.info;authpriv.*;remoteauth.crit   /var/log/authinfo.log
```

Then send a hangup signal to syslogd via

```
pkill -HUP -i -l syslogd
```

F.